# Get one-level directories in a path

Tags: powershell

Using Robocopy with the source E: causes error. So, I want get the subdirectories (and only the firsts subdirectories) of a path to copy with Robocopy after.

MyPath

```
MyPath/Examples
MyPath/Icons
MyPath/Icons/Another/ <------- NO
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$path = 'c:\mypath'
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-childItem supports wildcards. So this will get just the folders one level deep.

```
Get-ChildItem Mypath\*
```

So are you looking for something like this:

```
$source  = "Mypath"
$dest    =  "$env:temp"
$folders = Get-ChildItem "$source\*" -Directory
$folders | ForEach-Object{ robocopy $_.fullname "$dest\$_" -E }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using Robocopy with the source E: causes error.

Like this? It looks OK...

```
C:\>robocopy E: d:\t /LEV:1 /L

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 25 November 2014
   Source = E:\
     Dest : d:\t\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /L /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /LEV:1 /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                          13    E:\
          *EXTRA File                185        t.bat
            New File                  44        Track01.cda
            New File                  44        Track02.cda
            New File                  44        Track03.cda
            New File                  44        Track04.cda
etc.
```

Are you using the latest version?

Answer: use RoboCopy.